# SharePoint NavigationTermSet - Nested Terms

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-jsom

I'm trying to access the Term Store Navigation by SharePoint JSOM.

My Term Store Navigation is set up like this.

- Navigation Link 1
- - Sub Navigation Link 1
- - Sub Navigation Link 2
- Navigation Link 2

To access the Term Store Navigation use the following code.

```
this.getNavigationTermSet=function(currentTermStore,navTermSetId){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  var termSet = currentTermStore.getTermSet(navTermSetId);
  var navTermSet = SP.Publishing.Navigation.NavigationTermSet.getAsResolvedByWeb(this.clientContext,termSet, this.clientContext.get_web(), "GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider");
  this.clientContext.load(navTermSet,'Terms');
  this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(terms){
      deferred.resolve(navTermSet);
    },
    function(sender,args){
      deferred.reject(args.get_message());
    });
  return deferred;
}
```

The code returns a Termset Collection to the calling method that looks like this.

```
txCon.getNavigationTermSet(termStore,
   '6b361f3a-d8c5-40eb-89d0-c503a91eb033').then(function(navTerms){
       for(var i = 0 ; i<navTerms.get_terms().get_count();i++){
           var navTerm = navTerms.get_terms().getItemAtIndex(i); 
           console.log(navTerm.get_id() + " - "+ navTerm.get_taxonomyName());
         }
}
```

I'm able to cycle through the Terms, but i can only access the first level. Is there anybody out there who can tell me how to access the second or any other nested level from there? Or is there a request for each child term necessary? i don't get it at the moment ;)

Comment: use `getAllTerms`. Docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312647.aspx

Comment: Thanks ,. I haven't recognized this method while surfing through the api documentation ! your answer pointed me to the correct direction and now the tree structure is working